# Connecting Dart to a .Net Core TCP Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, dart, tcp

I have a TCP socket server as a C# Console application and a C# client which I totally stole from [this Site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/)

They are working fine.

However, when I try to connect to that server with an dart client on the same machine. I can not connect. It will throw a time out error at the connect.

This is the dart code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  Socket socket = await Socket.connect("fe80::9c72:d354:9394:eeeb%3", 11111);
  print('connected');

  // listen to the received data event stream
  socket.listen((List<int> event) {
    print(utf8.decode(event));
  });

  // send hello
  socket.add(utf8.encode('hello'));

  // wait 5 seconds
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

  // .. and close the socket
  socket.close();
}
```

**Important Note:** "fe80::9c72:d354:9394:eeeb%3" is my local ipv6 adress and I made sure that socket is reachable from that adress by hardcoding it into the C# client. Worked marvelously.

Thank you for any answer

Comment: *where* does the timeout happen? at the connection? at the listen? or...? if at the connect: does it work if you use loopback (`::1` for IPv6) rather than a public IP?

Comment: It is at the connect command and I tried using 127.0.0.1 as loopback. It time out. I did not understand what you mean by public IP. the given IPv6 adress is my local ip. So it should not need an ip forwarding or anything.